# How to unit test that a list inputed to a method is less than 100

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have this test

```
[Test]
public void SaveInventoryItemLoad_Will_Call_WCF_Service_SaveInventoryItemLoad()
{ 
    adapter.SaveInventoryItemLoad(new List<InventoryItemLoadProxy>());
    itemMasterBusinessClientMock.Verify(x => x.SaveInventoryItemLoad(It.IsAny<List<InventoryItemLoadProxy>>()), Times.Once());
}
```

It was fine because I had tested on the WCF side the the method did what I wanted it to so all I needed was to say "Hey did you call the service? Yeah!". Now though... I need to break up said list in to chucks of 10 or less i.e. a list of 23 items would be three lists of 10, 10 and then 3. So step one is of course to write a unit test to verify that I haven't pushed more than ten items to the SaveInventoryItemLoad method. I can of course verify that method was called X amount of times but that isn't what I want. I want to make sure that the list supplied to the method was <= 10 but I can't seem to figure out how. I trolled the moq quickstart but don't see how I would do that.

I though this would do it somehow

```
// Verify setter with an argument matcher
mock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Value = It.IsInRange(1, 5, Range.Inclusive));
```

But I can't seem to make that work. I guess I have never run into this before. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
itemMasterBusinessClientMock.Verify(x => x.SaveInventoryItemLoad(It.Is<List<InventoryItemLoadProxy>>(l=>l.Count < 100)), Times.Once());
```

Here are few [examples](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Moq, only Rhino.Mocks, but I think you should be able to change your original code from `It.IsAny<List<InventoryItemLoadProxy>>` to constrain that it isn't *any* list, but rather a list with no more than 10 items.

From a quick look online, the syntax may be like `It.Is<List<InventoryItemLoadProxy>>(list => list.Count <= 10)`.